# How do I skip the 90s timeout in systemd

Tags: systemd, systemd-boot

Is it possible to interactively skip the 90s timeout in systemd? For example, when it is waiting for a disk to become available or user to log out? I know it will fail eventually, so can I just make it fail now? I hate just staring at the screen helplessly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible. Systemd is noninteractive.

In 2023, [Fedora 38 shortened the default timeout duration](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Shorter_Shutdown_Timer) to 45s.

Comment: what a shame. there are cases in which the ability to interact with hanging jobs at runtime makes a 3 work hours difference at best.

Answer (score 17):

You have two options:

1. You can set `TimeoutStopSpec=` on a specific UNIT to a specific value (in seconds*) to wait.  You can also set it to `infinity` in which case SIGKILL will never be sent (not recommended as you may end up with runaway services that are hard to debug).
2. Set `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=` inside `/etc/systemd/system.conf` (or `user.conf`, or in one of the `*.d` directories) to a default value that all UNITs that do not have `TimeoutStopSpec=` specified will use.  The deafult for this setting is the 90s you normally see.

Man page references:

- `man systemd.service` for `TimeoutStopSpec=`
- `man systemd-system.conf` for `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=`

---

<sub>* systemd also accepts time specs, e.g. "2min 3s".  That's extensively described in the man.</sub>

Comment: This is not interactive. When the systemd is already counting down the 90s, it is too late to make these changes and I am forced to sit though it helplessly.

Comment: @JiriDanek - that is because systemd isn't interactive, it is not meant to be.  Your tty process (in which you see the 90s) runs as a child of init (sytemd), i.e. the process showing (getty) the 90s is a child of the process counting them (systemd). And moreover, systemd ignores most signals.  systemd is not meant to be controlled by a random user in front of a tty (that would be a huge security risk).

Comment: I am primarily a desktop user, so I tend to see the things differently. Remember [Torvalds' daughter's printer](https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/1vyfmNCYpi5)? Many design inadequacies can be justified by security concerns.

Comment: @JiriDanek - systemd is not a **concern**, it would be an actual attack vector.  If you could aim a correct signal at the right moment you could (as a common user) disable a system service (e.g. SELinux).  Just go into /etc/systemd/system.con and add DefaultTimeout=3.  Or, better, fix the service that is failing.  The fact that some service always fail is not bad design of systemd, is bad design of the person who wrote the unit file.

Comment: In my specific case, the writer of the unit file is innocent. I just made a typo when copy-pasting a disk UUID. I simply found it irritating having to wait for full minute and half before systemd gave up mounting that and let me get into the system and fix the problem. The long timeout actually makes sense here. Except when I the admin know it doesn't.

Comment: @JiriDanek - Then I'd argue that the default delay should be longer.  It will ensure that sysadmins are more careful on not making typos (and/or testing their configuration changes) :D

Answer (score 7):

You can uncomment in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` the lines:

```
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
```

And change the value to what you consider appropriate.

Comment: Same as the other answer, this is not interactive. When the systemd is already counting down the 90s, it is too late to make these changes and I am forced to sit though it helplessly.